# how to create ansible template file that import data from additional template file

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have a template file called main.conf.j2 and this is distributed to all of my servers.  There is an additional server that needs to have a single configuration that should include the configuration of the main.conf.j2 file and additional configuration – I have named the file extra.conf.j2

My question is if there is a way to import the main.conf.j2 file inside the extra.conf.j2? the reason is that in case of a change in the main.conf.j2 I want to manage only a single file

main.conf.j2 – only in example

```
memory = {{memory.input}}
cpu = {{cpu.input}}
domain = {{domain.input}}
```

extra.conf.j2 – only in example

```
number.of.server = {{num_of_servers.input}}
**< here I want to include the main.conf.j2>**
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to deal with your requirement and my answer will not be exhaustive. I'll only give 2 examples that should more or less put you on the right track to adapt to your specific case.

If this is all just to specialize the template for one particular server, a simple jinja2 `if` statement should be enough.

`templates/main_singlefile.conf.j2`

```
{# Add a section if running on additional_host #}
{% if inventory_hostname == 'additional_host' %}
number.of.server = {{ num_of_servers.input }}
{% endif %}
memory = {{ memory.input }}
cpu = {{ cpu.input }}
domain = {{ domain.input }}
```

You can then deploy the same template everywhere and it will adapt depending on the `inventory_hostname`.

If you need to adapt that template to several different hosts, the above might not scale very well. In that case, taking advantage of the [jinja2 extension mechanism](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#template-inheritance) might be better suited.

We could imagine something like:

- `templates/main_base.conf.j2`

  ```
  {# specific overridable block empty in base #}
  {% block extra %}
  {% endblock extra %}
  memory = {{ memory.input }}
  cpu = {{ cpu.input }}
  domain = {{ domain.input }}
  ```
- `templates/main_addtional_host.conf.j2`

  ```
  {% extends "main_base.conf.j2" %}
  {% block extra %}
  number.of.server = {{ num_of_servers.input }}
  {% endblock extra %}
  ```
- and a task that will load the specific template if it exists using the [`ansible.builtin.first_found` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/first_found_lookup.html)

  ```yaml
  - name: Deploy template from inherited template if exists else use base
    vars:
      candidate_templates:
        - templates/main_{{ inventory_hostname }}.conf.j2
        - templates/main_base.conf.j2
    ansible.builtin.template:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: /path/on/target/to/base.conf
    loop: "{{ q('ansible.builtin.first_found', candidate_templates) }}"
  ```

---

Here is a full example to test both scenarii on localhost. The test project structure is like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── inventories
│   └── default
│       └── hosts.yml
├── templates
│   ├── main_additional_host.conf.j2
│   ├── main_base.conf.j2
│   └── main_singlefile.conf.j2
└── test.yml

3 directories, 5 files
```

The templates are exactly as described above.

The "fake" inventory in `inventories/default/hosts.yml` is:

```yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
  hosts:
    a_host:
      memory:
        input: 1
      cpu:
        input: 2
      domain:
        input: my_domain.com
    additional_host:
      memory:
        input: 10
      cpu:
        input: 20
      domain:
        input: other_domain.com
      num_of_servers:
        input: 100
```

The `test.yml` playbook is adapted to test only on localhost:

```yaml
---
- name: Adaptative template demo
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: "Example specific: create example host dirs in tmp to deploy results"
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: /tmp/tpldemo/{{ inventory_hostname }}/{{ item }}
        state: directory
      loop:
        - single_file
        - inheritance

    - name: Deploy template from single file example
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: main_singlefile.conf.j2
        dest: /tmp/tpldemo/{{ inventory_hostname }}/single_file/base.conf

    - name: Deploy template from inherited template if exists else use base
      vars:
        candidate_templates:
          - templates/main_{{ inventory_hostname }}.conf.j2
          - templates/main_base.conf.j2
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: /tmp/tpldemo/{{ inventory_hostname }}/inheritance/base.conf
      loop: "{{ q('ansible.builtin.first_found', candidate_templates) }}"
```

Runing the playbook against the fake inventory gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/default/ test.yml 

PLAY [Adaptative template demo] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Example specific: create example host dirs in tmp to deploy results] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [additional_host] => (item=single_file)
changed: [a_host] => (item=single_file)
changed: [a_host] => (item=inheritance)
changed: [additional_host] => (item=inheritance)

TASK [Deploy template from single file example] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [a_host]
changed: [additional_host]

TASK [Deploy template from inherited template if exists else use base] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [a_host] => (item=/tmp/test/templates/main_base.conf.j2)
changed: [additional_host] => (item=/tmp/test/templates/main_additional_host.conf.j2)

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
a_host                     : ok=3    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
additional_host            : ok=3    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And you can check that the templates where generated as expected in both cases:

```
$ for f in /tmp/tpldemo/*/*/base.conf; do echo -e "$f\n-----------"; cat $f; echo -en "\n\n"; done
/tmp/tpldemo/additional_host/inheritance/base.conf
-----------
number.of.server = 100
memory = 10
cpu = 20
domain = other_domain.com


/tmp/tpldemo/additional_host/single_file/base.conf
-----------
number.of.server = 100
memory = 10
cpu = 20
domain = other_domain.com


/tmp/tpldemo/a_host/inheritance/base.conf
-----------
memory = 1
cpu = 2
domain = my_domain.com


/tmp/tpldemo/a_host/single_file/base.conf
-----------
memory = 1
cpu = 2
domain = my_domain.com
```